# Cypress test with multiple interceptors

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I am trying to write cypress tests that check if data is received into my data table from the API.

One test to check the data, another test to check for an error message if there is no data from the API.

To simulate the API's response (one with data and one without) I am using cy.intercept().

I can't seem to get two separate intercepts to work within my single test file.

What is the recommended procedure to test multiple different intercepts in the same cypress test file, or should they be in separate files?

Any help appreciated!

```
    describe('Display Data Page', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {

        // Fake the backend Http response using the json file in our cypress fixtures folder.
        cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', {fixture:'my_data.json'}).as('my_data');

        cy.visit('/display-data');
        
    });

    it('Should display a list of my data', () => {

        cy.wait('@my_data');

        cy.get('.dataGrid').should('not.be.empty');
        cy.get('.dataGrid').should("contain", "Blah");
  
    });

    it('Should display a error message when api is offline', () => {

        // Reply with a HTTP 400 bad request to test error message
        cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', {status: 400}).as('my_error_data');

        cy.wait('@my_error_data');

        cy.get('.errorMessage').should('not.be.empty');
        cy.get('.errorMessage').should("contain", "Error: API is non-responsive!");
  
    });

});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic problem is that the intercept `my_error_data` is being set too late.

Since intercepts are listeners, they need to be set up before they code that triggers the backend call. That trigger is `cy.visit()`, but in the second test it runs before the intercept is set up.

Move the visit out of the `beforeEach()` and into the tests to fix it.

```js
it('Should display a list of my data', () => {

  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', {fixture:'my_data.json'})
    .as('my_data')

  cy.visit('/display-data')
  cy.wait('@my_data')

  ... 
})

it('Should display a error message when api is offline', () => {

  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', {status: 400})
    .as('my_error_data')

  cy.visit('/display-data')
  cy.wait('@my_error_data')

  ...
})
```

---

#### Keeping the beforeEach()

If you really want to keep the `beforeEach()` structure, make the `StaticResponse` part of the `cy.intercept()` dynamic.

You would only need one intercept with that pattern.

```js
let staticResponses = [
  {fixture:'my_data.json'},
  {status: 400}
]

beforeEach(() => {

  const response = staticResponses.shift() // extract 1st response and reduce array

  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', response)
    .as('my_data')

  cy.visit('/display-data')
})

it('Should display a list of my data', () => {
  cy.wait('@my_data')
  ...
})

it('Should display a error message when api is offline', () => {
  cy.wait('@my_data')  // same alias
  ...
})
```

---

#### Example test

Here's an example test to verify the principle.

It turns out that Cypress is smart enough to know when the `staticResponse` is a fixture that should be sent as `body`, and when the object represents the whole response.

```js
let staticResponses = [
  {fixture:'example.json'},
  {statusCode: 400}             // use statusCode instead of status
]

beforeEach(() => {
  const response = staticResponses.shift() // extract 1st response and reduce array

  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', response)
    .as('my_data')

  cy.visit('/display-data')
})

it('Should display a list of my data', () => {
  cy.wait('@my_data')
    .its('response.body')
    .should('have.property', 'email', 'hello@cypress.io')
})

it('Should display a error message when api is offline', () => {
  cy.wait('@my_data')
    .its('response')
    .should('have.property', 'statusCode', 400)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't get the before each to work unfortunately. Also my {status: 400} was actually being added int he body of the request not the header. Better to just not do an intercept for the error scenario, then it will fail as the api isn't online anyway

Comment: Yes, you're right about `{status:400}` needing to be in the header, I completely missed that. Let me check it out.

Comment: Turns out it's the `statusCode` that needs to be set.

Comment: The `beforeEach()` approach is the only approach that worked on my end. I am using `it('test name', async () => {...test...});` async tests though so I am unsure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `Cypress.env()` to pass the response, just use a simple function

```js
function setupIntercept(response) {
  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', response)
    .as('my_data')
  cy.visit('/display-data')
}

it('Should display a list of my data', () => {

  setupIntercept({fixture:'example.json'})

  cy.wait('@my_data')
    .its('response.body')
    .should('have.property', 'email', 'hello@cypress.io')
})

it('Should display a error message when api is offline', () => {

  setupIntercept({statusCode: 400})

  cy.wait('@my_data')
    .its('response')
    .should('have.property', 'statusCode', 400)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [Cypress environment variables](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env) in [the test configuration (the `it`, `context`, or `describe` blocks).](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-5-Test-Configuration) We can utilize this to set custom responses in each `it`, while keeping a shared `beforeEach` block.

```js
    describe('Display Data Page', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', Cypress.env('getDataResponse')).as('my_data');
        cy.visit('/display-data');
        cy.wait('@my_data');
    });

    it('Should display a list of my data', { env: { getDataResponse: { fixture: 'my_data.json' } } },() => {
        cy.get('.dataGrid').should('not.be.empty');
        cy.get('.dataGrid').should("contain", "Blah");
    });

    it('Should display a error message when api is offline', { env: { getDataResponse: { status: 400 } } }, () => {
        cy.get('.errorMessage').should('not.be.empty');
        cy.get('.errorMessage').should("contain", "Error: API is non-responsive!");
    });
});
```

It may be duplicative to include the `cy.wait()` as Cypress *should* wait for the `cy.visit()` to complete before continuing, but without seeing your website, I can't say for certain.

Additionally, if you had a it where *most* tests require one response (say the `fixture: 'my_data.json`), you could set that as the default ([via the nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) and clearing the `'getDataResponse'` environment variable).

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.intercept('GET', 'https://localhost:3000/GetData', 
    Cypress.env('getDataResponse') ?? { fixture: 'my_data.json' }
  );
});

afterEach(() => {
  Cypress.env('getDataResponse', null)
});
```

There are drawbacks to clearing the data in an `afterEach`, but assuming you reset the values prior to any other actions in the `afterEach`, you shouldn't encounter most of them.